# Fabric.js 3.4 - Dynamically adjusting SVG strokeWidth on Group or Polygon

Tags: javascript, svg, fabricjs, stroke

I have an app (based on fabric.js 3.4) that allows the user to adjust the strokeWith of an SVG  ( Group or Polygon ) in real-time via a slider. However, this a seems to break the image. So, for example if I have an SVG (Group) of a smiley face with 2 circles (strokes) for eyes, a stroked mouth and outer circle -- updating the slider to increase stroke width with deforms the image such that eyes, etc start overlapping/shifting (i.e. do not scale together as a unit/image) or, the image "flashes" - disappearing/reappearing as the slider is moved.

The code being used to update is:

```
 var value = //get value from slider widget
 var obj = canvas.getActiveObject();
   if (obj && obj.type == "group") {          
        for (i = 0; i < obj._objects.length; i++) {
            if (obj._objects[i]) {
                obj._objects[i].set({ strokeWidth: value });
            }
        }      
    } else if (obj && obj.type == "polygon") {
        obj.set({ strokeWidth: value });
    }
    canvas.renderAll();
```

Is this the wrong way to go about it?
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

the right way of scaling the elements inside the group is to change the `scale` value of the group itself:

`group.set({ scaleX: value, scaleY: value })`

If however you need to change some values of the objects inside the group, then assure to call [addWithUpdate](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Group.html#addWithUpdate) near you call to `canvas.renderAll()` to update all the necessary values of the group. Please refer to my recent reply [fabric.js 3.6 - Bounding box for group doesn't update when grouped objects are changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63256748/fabric-js-3-6-bounding-box-for-group-doesnt-update-when-grouped-objects-are-c) for some additional details on that.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Adam. Though I didn't want to scale the SVG. In other words, if my SVG sits on the canvas at 400px x 400px I want the stroke to become fatter/thinner based on slider input without affecting the scale. ( still want it 400x400px ). Not sure how I would empoly AddWithUpdate as I am not adding anything new to the canvas, just changing the storkeWidth of what's already there.

Comment: Well, actually, I don't mind if the size has to grow/shrink a bit to accommodate a thicker/thinner stroke width, but scaling isn't my main goal.

Comment: I tried setting strokeWidth on the entire group --  obj.set({ strokeWidth: value });-- but that seems to just increase the padding area around the SVG without affecting the SVG itself.